# selenium getSessionId did not get JsessionID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, remotewebdriver

When I use `getSessionId()` to fetch Session ID of current window which should be identified by current `driver`. Code like this.

```
String sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId().toString();
```

The value of `sessionId` is different with `JSESSIONID` in chrome `Resources->Cookies->JSESSIONID`.

Does `RemoteWebDriver` not get the correct value? How to do get correct session id? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
//Assume Wed Driver is initiated properly 
Cookie cookie= driver.manage().getCookieNamed("JSESSIONID");
System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
```